# SendMessage thread-safety

Tags: winapi, mfc, sendmessage

Consider the following code snippet:

```
CWnd * wnd = /*...*/;
int integer = 1;
integer = 10;
std::function < void ( ) > fn = [&] ()
{
    assert(integer == 10); // ??? (1)
    integer = 20;
}
wnd->SendMessage(WM_INVOKE_FN, NULL, (LPARAM)&fn);
assert(integer == 20); // ??? (2)
```

`WM_INVOKE_FN` processing function is defined as follows:

```
afx_msg LRESULT CTestDlg::OnInvokeFn(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    (*(std::function < void () > *) lParam)();
    return 0;
}
```

**The question:** Is the code above being executed on the thread other than one that created `wnd` still thread safe? More specifically, may `(1)` and/or `(2)` fail and why?

**My reasoning:**

Neither 1, nor 2 can fail.

1. We don't know (do we?) how `SendMessage` is actually implemented. But we can (can we?) assume that the function internally uses memory barriers to ensure the message queue is always in a valid state. Therefore, `fn` is actually executed after the memory barrier and, if the compiler preserves the instruction order, sees `integer == 10`.
2. `SendMessage` is external (`User32.dll` member) function so passing the `(LPARAM)&fn` as an argument is an observable action (is it?) (the compiler knows nothing about which thread will execute the `fn`; `integer` is captured by reference and is accessed inside the `fn`) that prohibits reordering of write(s) to `integer` and call to `SendMessage`.
3. `SendMessage` blocks the caller thread at least until the `OnInvokeFn` returns. Again, we can assume some memory barriers are involved in waiting process. So, `integer == 20` after `SendMessage` returns.

Is my proof correct? Any ideas?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156402/discussion-on-question-by-kalaider-sendmessage-thread-safety).

Comment: `3` is not correct: [When can a thread receive window messages?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040608-00/?p=38983/).

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, `SendMessage` acts in a more complex way, but in this example i believe we can assume it is "correct". We confine ourselves to considering the situation is ideal, i.e. (a) the the gui thread is alive at least as long as our background thread is alive, (b) it is certain to process the message and (c) the `integer` is accessed only from the listed code. In such case the only interesting behavior of the `SendMessage` is `enter SendMessage -> barrier? -> ... wait ... -> barrier? -> leave SendMessage`.